# How refresh Index(Parent), from inside another iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, frame

Need help..

I have a page (index.html), inside of the index.html have a iframe to main.html.
And inside of main.html, i access other pages. Example (productlist.html).

In top of Index.html its have a cart with quantity products.

i Wanna add a new product in (form or input) in productlist.html and refresh index.html, and continues in the productlist.html (NOT in the main.html).

How i do that?

index.html

```
    <li class="shoppingcar-total shoppingcar-resume-item">
        Total <span class="price">R$<ccom:content-block section="10022">
    <ccom:field id="TotalGeral" type="virtual" /></ccom:content-block></span>
        </li>

 <iframe src="Get?id_sec=111" id="main_frame"  name="main_frame" class="margin123" width="100%" scrolling="no"  frameborder="0" seamless="seamless"> Nao e possivel mostrar o frame</iframe>
```

main.html (Get?id_sec=111)

```
     <form action="Get?id_sec=116" method="post">
      <input type="submit" class="buy-button primary-button minimalist-button"
 title="Adicionar ao carrinho" id="boughtbutton1" name="Adicionar" value="Refresh" onsubmit="window.opener.location.reload();" />
    </form>
```

productlist.html (Get?id_sec=116)

```
ex: Item 1 price=$20
<button class="minus-button quantity-button button" type="submit" name="Adicionar" onclick="myFunc(document.getElementById('9950'));" value="-">
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `<iframe>` JavaScript code you can access the top frame (the main HTML document) by using `window.top`. Note that everything has to be on the same domain for this to work.

So let's assume you have a global function in your main document called `hello`. You'd call it like this from your JavaScript in the `<iframe>`:

```
window.top.hello();
```

There are also other ways to communicate, such as by listening for data posted by the [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) function.

Comment: Thanks for you helping.. How i apply this function in my case?